# Where is Twig service defined?

Tags: 8, theming

In `twig_render_template()`, I see this `drupal_container()->get('twig')->loadTemplate($template_file)->render($variables)`. But I can not see where the twig service is defined.

Comment: I found it: \Drupal\Core\CoreServiceProvider::registerTwig()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class that registers the Twig service is [`CoreServiceProvider`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!CoreServiceProvider.php/class/CoreServiceProvider/8) which, in [CoreServiceProvider::register()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!CoreServiceProvider.php/function/CoreServiceProvider%3a%3aregister/8) (the method that every service provider needs to implement), uses the following code.

```
  // The 'request' scope and service enable services to depend on the Request
  // object and get reconstructed when the request object changes (e.g.,
  // during a subrequest).
  $container->addScope(new Scope('request'));
  $this->registerTwig($container);
  $this->registerModuleHandler($container);
```

The class used for the Twig service is not the [`Twig_Environment`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!vendor!twig!twig!lib!Twig!Environment.php/class/Twig_Environment/8) class that Symfony implements, but a subclass of it ([`TwigEnvironment`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Template!TwigEnvironment.php/class/TwigEnvironment/8)) implemented by Drupal.

The other registered service is twig.loader.filesystem, which uses the Symfony's [`Twig_Loader_Filesystem`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!vendor!twig!twig!lib!Twig!Loader!Filesystem.php/class/Twig_Loader_Filesystem/8) class.